# HDMI video card on older PC, how to tell if audio supported?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, hdmi, compatibility

I've been asked by a friend who isn't that computer-skilled, to suggest a cheap 2nd hand PCIe video card so he can connect his  PC to his new HDMI TV. The PC is S775-era G35 Intel/Dell running Microsoft MSDN DVD based Windows 8.1 (i.e. not a Dell customisation of Windows).

Finding a cheap AMD/nVidia PCIe video card with HDMI out, on EBay, is dead easy. But I remember issues many years ago with HDMI and audio. I can't remember if they were specific to older Windows, older Intel chipsets, older video card chips, or whatever.

(FWIW I'm on newer hardware myself and on Windows I tweak the disabled sound devices to copy any audio to HDMI as well as the usual speakers, so its a while since I did much with S775 gen boards, or had to worry about HDMI audio working automatically, and I'm remote from him so I won't be able to fix it on the spot if it arrives and there's an issue making it work).

How can I check/be sure whether a card I pick for him will handle HDMI audio properly?

Comment: It's a little old, but this answer may be of use to you: http://superuser.com/a/758346/169180

Comment: Informative but not an answer, what I really need is a checklist of (checkable-from-spec video card criteria) +(checkable-from-spec motherboard chipset criteria) that is known good for HDMI audio on Win 8.1. I can easy for example check things like chip/chipset, manufacturer, etc. If that means buying a generation later of something, for extra certainty, so be it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the HDMI port on a video card support audio?](http://superuser.com/questions/758341/does-the-hdmi-port-on-a-video-card-support-audio)

Comment: Same linkk as other comment, same reply applies.